# React Native + Firebase Google Login - onAuthStateChange vs Context

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm not sure how to use [onAuthStateChange](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state) and Context

I am populating user in context and then I check for user with:

```
import {useAuth} from '../contexts/auth';
const { usuario } = useAuth();

if(!user)....
```

I don't really understand how and why I should use onAuthStateChange.

Answer (score 0):

The onAuthStateChanged allows you receive an even when the authentication state changes, for example the user logs in or out. You can subscribe to the event and handle rendering based on the authentication state. Essentially you use it to populate or depopulate the user in your context.

For an example from the documentation [see here.](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state)